# IM trying to use SegmentedControll instead of Buttons for changing views

Tags: ios, xcode, uisegmentedcontrol

by default my "FirstSlection" is selected until I press "secondSelection" the Segway won't trigger
is there a way around ?

[librarian - User - Signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oc8Wg.jpg)
[here changing views from segwayIdentif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srfdb.jpg)

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: added pics to the post, this should help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the the action directly when view controller loads for the default selected item , then the trigger of segmented control selection will handle it in future clicks (when you manually click it)

Comment: I'm trying to do a login signup app , but yeah the default should get the job done  I guess thank.